# Sort mulitdimensional array by IP (SORT_NATURAL)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array with those values:

```
foreach($dbEntries as $ip){
    $ips[] = array(
        'location' => $ip->geLocation(),
        'description' => $ip->getDescription(),
        'note' => $ip->getNote(),
        'ipAddress' => $ip->getIpAddress(),
        'id' => $ip->getId(),
    );
}
```

Know I would like to sort this array by 'ipAddress' and usually I do it like this (PHP 7):

```
usort($ips, function($a, $b) {
   return $a['ipAddress'] <=> $b['ipAddress'];
});
```

But that doesn't sort correctly by the IP.
I read about the `SORT_NATURAL` flag for `array_multisort` but this gives me an error for: `$ips = array_multisort($ips['ipAddress'], SORT_NATURAL);`

> Warning: array_multisort(): Argument #1 is expected to be an array or a sort flag

How would I sort by IP naturally in a multidimensional array?

Comment: 1: use ip2long to make a number from the string, sort it, use long2ip to revert it back. 2: you call `$ips['ipAddress']` when your `$ips` array actually doesn't have such index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a key like `$ips['ipAddress']`. That's why you are getting that warning.
There's an example in [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) for multi sort that will help your problem.

First you need to collect all ips in one array to sort main one. Here is a sample how you can do it.

```
<?php
// Obtain a list of columns
$ipList = [];
foreach($dbEntries as $arrayKey => $ip){
    $ips[$arrayKey] = [
        'location' => $ip->geLocation(),
        'description' => $ip->getDescription(),
        'note' => $ip->getNote(),
        'ipAddress' => $ip->getIpAddress(),
        'id' => $ip->getId(),
    ];

    // Collect all ips with same array key 
    $ipList[$arrayKey] = $ip->getIpAddress();
}

// Sort the data with ipList natural order
// Add $ips as the last parameter, to sort by the common key

array_multisort($ipList, SORT_NATURAL, $ips);

// Now you can use sorted $ips array
print_r($ips);
```

Comment: this is perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
foreach ($dbEntries as $key => $row) {
    // replace 0 with the index of 'IpAddress'
    $entries[$key]  = $row[0];
   }

array_multisort($entries, SORT_DESC, $dbEntries );
```